# Reading from tty in piped shell

Tags: command-line, zsh

I have a script that is run like this:

curl https://example.com/install.sh | zsh -

The script needs to read from use input:

```
read "human_name?Your human name ?"</dev/tty
```

The problem is the user sees the input and can enter their response but the response is not stored in human_name.

Example:

```
cat <<EOM | zsh -
read "human_name?Your human name ?"</dev/tty   
if [ -z "$human_name" ] ; then echo "tears" ; else echo "HI" $human_name; fi
EOM
```

Results in:

```
Your human name ?Pat
tears
```

Any guidance?

Comment: First of all, [don't do that](https://curlpipesh.tumblr.com/). Even if the source is secure, if curl cuts out, you may end up in a bad state as you execute a half-complete script.

Comment: @ChrisDown - Noted. Not a major issue in this case as script is short and run internally. Ease of copy and paste is most important to get internal acceptance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always read from the terminal by redirecting from `/dev/tty`, as long as the program is not a background job. If it's a background job, it'll be paused by a SIGTTIN until it gets switched to the foreground.

The problem with your script is not reading from the terminal, but what you do with what you've read. You used a here document with interpolation, so `$human_name` is interpolated while constructing the here document, and it's empty at the time. You need to either use a here document without interpolation or quote the dollar signs so that the shell you run with `zsh -` sees and parses them.

```
cat <<'EOM' | zsh -
read "human_name?Your human name ?"</dev/tty   
if [ -z "$human_name" ] ; then echo "tears" ; else echo "HI" $human_name; fi
EOM
```

Comment: And for clarity, to those who follow the </dev/tty is needed for the prompt to happen AND the 'zsh' works without the '-'